# how to add toggler button to collapse the header in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, navbar

i'm new to web development so, i'm finding it difficult to add the collapse toggler in my code.i have tried different method and seems not to be gettting it please can someone assist here

here is my code.

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <header class="blog-header py-3 container">
            <div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="col-4 pt-1">
            
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">Subscribe</a>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="2611logo2.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
                <a class="text-muted" href="#">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="mx-3"><circle cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="7.5"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="15.8" y2="15.8"></line></svg>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Sign up</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </header>
            
                <div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
                    <nav class=" nav d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Shop</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Hoodies</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Accessoriess</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Tracksuit</a>
                    <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Shoes</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming you're running jQuery).

```
$('header').toggle();
```

BUT once you run that you won't be able to get it back.  You need a button or something to use as a trigger.

```
$("the-css-or-id-of-the-thing-you-click").click(function(){
  $("header").toggle();
});
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp